# I have a problem using the messagebox.askokcancel function in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, popup, messagebox

I am trying to make a message pop up when a certain action is done, but the ok button doesn't work.

```
def delete_all_songs():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Delete all Songs","Are you sure you want to delete all Songs"):
        print("doing")
        filelisttodelete = [f for f in os.listdir("C:/MusicPlayer/Songs/") if f.endswith(".mp3")]
        for f in filelisttodelete:
            os.remove(os.path.join("C:/MusicPlayer/Songs/", f))

        songs_box.delete(0, END)
        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: When you click ```Cancel``` it returns ```False```. Have you tried printing it?

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: if i click on the ok button nothing happens.

Comment: ```x=messagebox.askokcancel("Delete all Songs","Are you sure you want to delete all Songs")```, ```print(x)```

Comment: It works fine for me and "doing" is shown in the console when "OK" button is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

The [`askokcancel()`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/tkMessageBox.html) function "…returns a bool value: True for “OK” or “Yes” choices, False for “No” or “Cancel” choices" — you have to use its return value to make a message pop up. Here's a standalone runnable example:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

def delete_all_songs():
    if messagebox.askokcancel("Delete all Songs",
                              "Are you sure you want to delete all Songs?"):
#        filelisttodelete = [f for f in os.listdir("C:/MusicPlayer/Songs/")
#                             if f.endswith(".mp3")]
#        for f in filelisttodelete:
#            os.remove(os.path.join("C:/MusicPlayer/Songs/", f))
#
#        songs_box.delete(0, END)
#        pygame.mixer.music.stop()
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "All Songs Deleted")
    else:
        messagebox.showinfo("Info", "Song Deletion Canceled")

win = Tk()
Button(win, text="Test", command=delete_all_songs).pack()
Button(win, text="Quit", command=win.quit).pack()
win.mainloop()
```